# SQL query date into new columns with unique ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, report

I have the following columns, a 5 digit ID, date and a value. The ID repeats only when a new date is present.

```
ID        Date     Value
11111  2014-12-31  45 
22222  2014-12-31  435 
33333  2014-12-31  11 
11111  2014-12-30  5 
22222  2014-12-30  2245 
33333  2014-12-30  86 
11111  2014-12-29  43 
22222  2014-12-29  4678 
33333  2014-12-29  2494
```

I am trying to create an SQL query that will display the following (dates are column names):

```
ID      2014-12-31     2014-12-30       2014-12-29 
11111      45               5               43 
22222     435              2245            4678 
33333      11               86             2494
```

What is the best way of doing this using MS SQL.

Thanks

Comment: how many different dates do you have?

Comment: Search for `PIVOT examples`, or `dynamic PIVOT examples` should get you there quickly.  Also hit the `{}` button after highlighting sample data or code to format it as code in your question.

Comment: You have two challenges here. You are trying to do a dynamic cross tab or pivot. Additionally you are then trying to dynamically use the values from one column as the column names for the dynamically pivoted data. This kind of thing is a lot easier in the front end. It is difficult and often very slow in sql.

Comment: Thank you all. I will learn more about PIVOT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by the comments, you need to PIVOT your data. Here is one way using a Dynamic Crosstab.

Read this article by Jeff Moden for reference: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048

```
CREATE TABLE temp(
    ID      INT,
    [Date]  DATE,
    Value   INT
)
INSERT INTO temp VALUES
(11111, '2014-12-31', 45),
(22222, '2014-12-31', 435),
(33333, '2014-12-31', 11),
(11111, '2014-12-30', 5),
(22222, '2014-12-30', 2245),
(33333, '2014-12-30', 86),
(11111, '2014-12-29', 43),
(22222, '2014-12-29', 4678),
(33333, '2014-12-29', 2494);

DECLARE @sql1 VARCHAR(2000) = ''
DECLARE @sql2 VARCHAR(2000) = ''
DECLARE @sql3 VARCHAR(2000) = ''

SELECT @sql1 = 
'SELECT
    ID
'

SELECT @sql2 = @sql2 + 
'   ,MIN(CASE WHEN [Date] = CAST(''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [Date], 120) + ''' AS Date) THEN Value END) AS [' 
    + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [Date], 120) + ']'+ CHAR(10)
FROM(
    SELECT  DISTINCT [Date] FROM temp
)t
ORDER BY [Date] DESC

SELECT @sql3 = 
    'FROM temp
    GROUP BY ID
    ORDER BY ID'

PRINT (@sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3)
EXEC (@sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3)

DROP TABLE temp
```

**EDIT:**
If you want to use fixed name, you'll want to assign a number for each `Date`. This can be done using `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT @sql2 = @sql2 + 
'   ,MIN(CASE WHEN [Date] = CAST(''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [Date], 120) + ''' AS Date) THEN Value END) AS [Date' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, rn) + ']'+ CHAR(10)
FROM(
    SELECT 
        [Date],
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Date])
    FROM (
        SELECT  DISTINCT [Date]FROM temp
    )x
)t
ORDER BY [Date] DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work fine. If I ever want to change this script to display Fixed column names like Date1, Date2, Date3.... what should be changed?